Mark folder as src in VS Code python project (remote development via ssh)
I am working on a python project via VS Code remote ssh access.
The Structure of the project is roughly equal to the following:
Project/
├─ src/
│  ├─ folder1/
│  │  ├─ subfolder/
│  │  │  ├─ new_file.py
│  ├─ file.py
├─ .gitignore

When executing the python files, I always have to specify the PYTHONPATH because otherwise imports are not found.
Additionally new_file.py creates data that that is supposed to be saved in folder/subfolder/out (seen relatively to the src folder), however when executing folder/subfolder/out is created in relation to the Project folder instead of src.
When using PyCharm this problem can simply be solved by marking the src folder as src. How can I achieve this using VS Code?
I tried suggestions from How to set the root directory for Visual Studio Code Python Extension? however they didn’t help in terms of not changing the behaviour in any kind.
